# Does garbage collection dispose of Threads if you assign a new Thread to a variable

Tags: c#

Suppose i have this example code

```
Thread foo;
foo = new Thread(function1);
foo.Start();

foo = new Thread(function2);
foo.Start();
```

Will the old thread with function1 be terminated by the garbage collection and dispose of it or will it keep running in the background?

Comment: It's not too hard to test that, is it?

Comment: See for example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TOh5xl

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, that answers it. On another note, is it possible to terminate it somehow as the reference to it no longer exists?

Comment: Not automatically. You could use a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), though. But that means, you need to actively cancel it. It wouldn't fire just by nullifying or reassigning the variable.